# Spring 3.0 localization not working in tomcat, only from jetty locally

Tags: java, spring, localization, locale

I am struggling with getting the localization to work when I deploy my app to tomcat.
I've got this setup in my applicationContext.xml:

```
<!-- Configures Handler Interceptors -->    
<mvc:interceptors>
    <!-- Changes the locale when a 'locale' request parameter is sent; e.g. /?locale=de -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" >
        <property name="paramName" value="locale" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

<!-- Saves a locale change using a cookie -->
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="no" />
</bean>

<!-- Application Message Bundle -->
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true" />
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:language" />
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
</bean>
```

Now, the localization works just fine when I run it from Jetty locally.
It's when I run the app from tomcat that it consequentially displays the language from the language_en.properties file, not my default file language.properties. And when I try to change the locale with ?locale=no (norwegian) nothing happends to the language on the site, but the log shows that the locale is actually changed to "no".

Has someone got any solutions or suggestion to solution to this, or maybe an alternative way of setting up the localization. I am open for anything and everything.

Comment: When accessing the app in Tomcat, do you see the locale cookie being set in the response? Are you positive all of the `language_*.properties` files are being deployed to Tomcat?

Comment: matt b: Yes the cookie is beeing set, and it stores the correct locale, but the language file corresponding to that locale isn't loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try

classpath*:language

ie, search ALL classpaths. Depending on where you are deploying your resource bundles, they may end up in different places in the classloader hierarchy in tomcat and jetty.

Comment: Then I would try to hard-code to the actual location of the language resource bundle, like WEB-INF/classes/language.

Comment: That didn't work either. What I think is so wierd about all this is that it loads the language_en.properties not the default language.properties file. I'm not sure how to debug this properly either...

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY! I solved it!

```
I had to set the JvmOptions: 
-Duser.language=no 
-Duser.region=NO
```

in order for tomcat to use the `language.properties` and not the `language_en.properties` file.
And for some strange reason it now also works when setting the locale (?locale=en) to english too.

Comment: Hope this will help some non-english-as-default-locale programmers in the future :P